# How to update embedded document in MongoDB with Doctrine ODM

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine, php-mongodb, doctrine-odm

I'm unable to find how to update embedded documents with Doctrine Mongo ODM in Symfony2. I have a class called Page with many embedded documents "Comments" and I want to use createQueryBuilder to update specific comment. Here is a simple class that I have:

class Page
{

```
protected $id;

/** @MongoDB\EmbedMany */
private $pageComment = array();
```

}

I searched the whole internet, but I don't see to find any info on how to update subdocuments of a document with Doctrine ODM query builder. I will be thankful for any information as I'm new to both Doctrine and Mongo. In simple words I want to update specific comment in a page after searching for it by id.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can update only one field at time (instead of `pageComment.$`):

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('page')
    ->update()
    ->field('id')->equals($pageId)
    ->field('pageComment.id')->equals($pageCommentId)
    ->field("pageComment.$.field1")->set($field1)
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wan to use queryBuilder use this

```
$dm->createQueryBuilder('Page')
    ->update()
    ->field('page.pageComment')->set( <$newupdatePageCommentObj> )
    ->field('id')->equals('<matchedId>')
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

Or When you generate setters and getters for a EmbedMany member variable it will generate add and remove member functions inside your class. so in your case these will be member functions:

```
public function addPageComment(type_hint_with_your_pageComment_document $pageComment )
{
    $this->pageComment[] = $pageComment;
}
public function removePageComment( type_hint_with_your_pageComment_document $pageComment )
{
    $this->items->removeElement( $pageComment );
}
```

So you can use addPageComment() function which will add it if does not exists and will update it will its already there.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $yourArrayPageComment = array(
  "id" => new \MongoId($pageCommentId),
  "field1" => $field1,
  ...
)

 $this->createQueryBuilder('page')
            ->update()
            ->field('id')->equals($pageId)
            ->field('pageComment.id')->equals($pageCommentId)
            ->field("pageComment.$")->set($yourArrayPageComment)
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute();
```

Comment: Didn't you get an error like `Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\MyProject\vendor\doctrine\mongodb-odm\lib\Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Persisters\DocumentPersister.php line 998` when using this code?

Comment: That was a bug in mongodb-odm, fixed as of https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/pull/661.