# Mongodb update embedded document doctrine (zero-length keys are not allowed, did you use $ with double quotes?)

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to update an embedded mongodb document with Doctrine: I want to search for the embedded documents (within their parents..) and then update the child document within its parent. Basically, this is my datastructure:

```
class a{
    protected $id;
    protected $objectB;
    portected $myArray;  // type of class c
}


class b{
    protected $id;
    protected $attribute;
    protected $realCoolAttribute;
}

class c{
    protected $id;
    protected $attribute;
    protected $realCoolAttribute;
}
```

All of these attributes have their getters and setters within their class. But I also had a try using public attributes instead of protected ones.

Using a [similar query to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15950080/how-to-update-embedded-document-in-mongodb-with-doctrine-odm)

I am able to search and even to delete the embedded document. I am also able to change simple attributes. But, if I try to change a complex attribute, which is member of an array or if the attribute I want to change is a whole document (and not any more a simple value..), I got the following error message:

> zero-length keys are not allowed, did you use $ with double quotes?

The new document I wants to update instead is complete, with attributes and Id.

I would appreciate any help

Comment: Welcome to SO. Consider posting the relevant Repository & Controller methods.